# Initialize subclass of NSObject

Tags: objective-c

MySubClass.h

```
@interface MySubClass : NSObject
{
}
```

MySubClass.m

```
@interface MySubClass ()

@end

@implementation MySubClass
-(MySubClass*)initMySubClass:(id)view{
  // initialize my SubClass
}
@end
```

What is the proper way to write a custom initializer if I subclass from NSObject?

Do I need to use "init" inside my initializer?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(instancetype)initMySubClass:(id)view {
    if(self = [super init]) {

        // custom initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Apple docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init

Note that, for `NSObject` itself, the `init` method just returns `self`. It is still best practice to call `init`, however. For example, what if Apple were to include additional initialisation there in the future? Or, what if you want to change the superclass?

Comment: assignment in the conditional will generate a compiler warning.  suppress with an extra line of code or an extra set of parens.  `[self init]` is a better choice than super, if this subclass implements it, and harmless if it doesn't.

Comment: The assignment has never generated a compiler warning for me (although I remember wondering why - I assumed it was just because this is a very common idiom).

Comment: Maybe you have `-Wno-parentheses` specified.

Comment: I got error: for self = [super init]  ,   can't assign to self to outside of method in the init family

Comment: @danh I think -Wno-idiomatic-parentheses, will work.

Comment: @elliptic00 Does your method name begin with `init`?

Answer (score 0):

@michaelrccurtis's answer is correct. But [here's more thorough documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) on how you generally do initialization in Obj-C.

Basically, every class can have a designated initializer and if you subclass it, you must override that initializer and call super from your subclass's designated initializer. The graphic in the docs makes this clearer.